# Tensorflow: List of Tensors for Cost

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to work with LSTMs in Tensor Flow. I found a tutorial online where a set of sequences is taken in and the objective function is composed of the last output of the LSTM and the known values. However, I would like to have my objective function use information from each output. Specifically, I am trying to have the LSTM learn the set of sequences (i.e. learn all the letters in words in a sentence).:

```
cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units)
inputs = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[batch_size,input_size]) for _ in range(seq_len)]
result = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size,input_size]) for _ in range(seq_len)]

W_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units,input_size], stddev=0.01))     
b_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_size], stddev=0.01))

outputs, states = rnn.rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)   

losses = []

for i in xrange(len(outputs)):
    final_transformed_val = tf.matmul(outputs[i],W_o) + b_o
    losses.append(tf.nn.softmax(final_transformed_val))

cost = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
```

Doing this results in the error:

```
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

How should I fix this issue? Does the `tf.reduce_mean()` take in a list of tensor values, or is there some special tensor object that takes them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `losses` is a Python list. TensorFlow's [`reduce_mean()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_mean) expects a single tensor, not a Python list.

```
losses = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, losses), [-1, size])
```

where size is the number of values you're taking a softmax over should do what you want. See [concat()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat)

But, one thing I notice in your code that seems a bit odd, is that you have a list of placeholders for your inputs, whereas the code in [the TensorFlow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) uses an order 3 tensor for inputs. Your input is a list of order 2 tensors. I recommend looking over the code in the tutorial, because it does almost exactly what you're asking about.

One of the main files in that tutorial is [here](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py). In particular, line 139 is where they create their cost. 
Regarding your input, lines 90 and 91 are where the input and target placeholders are setup. The main takeaway in those 2 lines is that an entire sequence is passed in in a single placeholder rather than with a list of placeholders.

See line 120 in the ptb_word_lm.py file to see where they do their concatenation.

Comment: Got it, I misunderstood. I deleted my answer :) You may want to just show the code example from the tutorial in your post, as it may help newcomers (and I'd like to understand too).

Comment: The code I was talking about is at https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#139 and the part about the inputs is at line 90 in that file. num_steps in that file's line 90 is the same (roughly) as seq_len in OP's code. Would you suggest inlining the whole __init__ method, or just provide the link to the file?

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah that's a very large method. I think the link to the file, with a few relevant lines and a tiny bit of explanation, would make it the most clear. Your post seems to be a great starting point, but seeing a "correct example" of the portions of the code that OP isn't doing the right way would be very helpful I think.

Another strategy I use sometimes is to just paste the whole method/class but replace the irrelevant lines with `# ...` to shorten it.

Comment: The links to the code examples are dead. e.g. [https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py]

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py is where that code is now, although the line numbers I mentioned before no longer make sense

Answer (score 2):

Working example, check [notebook](https://github.com/ragulpr/jupyter-notebooks/blob/master/lstm_as_list_of_steps.ipynb):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn, rnn_cell
print(tf.__version__) 
#> 0.8.0

batch_size  = 2
output_size = input_size  = 2
seq_len     = 10
num_units   = 2

cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units)
inputs = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size,input_size ]) for _ in xrange(seq_len)]
result = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size,output_size]) for _ in xrange(seq_len)]

W_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units,input_size], stddev=0.01))     
b_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_size],           stddev=0.01))

outputs, states = rnn.rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)   

losses = []

for i in xrange(seq_len):
    final_transformed_val = tf.matmul(outputs[i],W_o) + b_o
    losses.append(tf.squared_difference(result[i],final_transformed_val)) 

losses = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, losses), [-1, seq_len])
cost = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
```

To see this in action, you can feed the graph in a hacky way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

costs = []

# EXAMPLE
#  Learn cumsum over each sequence in x
# | t        | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  | ...|
# |----------|---|---|---|---|----|----|
# | x[:,0,0] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1  | ...|
# | x[:,0,1] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1  | ...|
# |          |   |   |   |   |    |    |
# | y[:,0,0] | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5  | ...|
# | y[:,0,1] | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5  | ...|

n_iterations = 300
for _ in xrange(n_iterations):
    x  = np.random.uniform(0,1,[seq_len,batch_size,input_size])
    y  = np.cumsum(x,axis=0)

    x_list = {key: value for (key, value) in zip(inputs, x)}
    y_list = {key: value for (key, value) in zip(result, y)}

    err,_ = sess.run([cost, step], feed_dict=dict(x_list.items()+y_list.items()))
    costs.append(err)

plt.plot(costs)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As tensorflow-beginner I have yet to find a unified way/best practices way of handling RNN's but as mentioned above I'm sure this isn't recommended. Liked your script as a very nice intro, thanks for the snippets. Also, there's things going on w.r.g to [implementation of scan and RNN-tuple-friendliness](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py) right now so be careful